Svelte transition with spring instead of duration+easing
I have been following the CSS-tricks article on running Svelte transitions with spring, instead of the usual duration+easing methos. The final result shows spring applied on a transform transition, which is nice and well. But what I wish to achieve is a slide transition with spring - which I have not managed to implement (height/width calculations on containers is more tricky than simple transforms, as mentioned in the article). Can someone kindly suggest how to achieve it?

To achieve a slide transition with a spring effect in Svelte, you can create a custom transition. Here’s a quick way to do it:

Import the necessary functions:
<script>
  import { spring } from 'svelte/motion';
</script>


Create the custom transition:
<script>
  function slideSpring(node, { stiffness = 0.2, damping = 0.25 } = {}) {
    const { height } = getComputedStyle(node);
    return {
      duration: 400,
      css: t => `
        overflow: hidden;
        height: ${t * parseFloat(height)}px;
      `,
      tick: t => spring(t, { stiffness, damping }),
    };
  }
</script>


Use the transition in your component:
<script>
  let show = false;
</script>

<button on:click={() => show = !show}>Toggle</button>

{#if show}
  <div transition:slideSpring>This is a spring slide transition.</div>
{/if}



This should give you a smooth spring slide transition. Adjust the stiffness and damping values as needed. For more details, check out the Svelte documentation.
